# UILabel word wrap feature leaving space even when sufficient space available for the word

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, ios-autolayout

The problem coming even in storyboard.

**The UILabel is having following properties:**

- numberOfLines = 0
- lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
- Constraints: Leading & Trailing 26 points to superview; vertically center.
- Custom Font: Medium 17 Points.

**As you can see the fourth word cannot fit in the first line and hence a problem by creating bad layout. If I remove the last word the sentence fits in one line completely or say the fourth word. If adding a word after it moves both of them to next line which leaves a lot of space. It should try to fit words without breaking or hyphenation as much as possible in one line. But clearly empty space is made even when word can fit.**

You can recreate this in a new project and observe the issue.

[image]

Comment: Use `label.sizeToFit()`. It may help.

Comment: still no help...

Comment: Apple designed the word-wrap algorithm to avoid "widows" -- that is, to avoid having a single word as the last line of a paragraph. Do a quick google search for `UILabel widows` and you'll find plenty of discussion explaining why it happens, and various approaches to try and get around it.

Comment: Hi @DonMag thanks for pointing me in right direction. However it doesn't have anything to do with word wrapping as it shows the same behavior in all line break modes.

Comment: It will behave differently if you set it to `Character Wrap`, but of course that will break in the middle of words, which I'm sure you don't want. Apple changed this around iOS 10 or 11 (as I recall). If it will work for your purposes, you could use non-scrollable, non-editable `UITextView` in place of your `UILabel` -- text view does *not* avoid widows and orphans (I should have said "orphans" to begin with, there's a difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to give this a try...

Subclass `UITextView`, disable scrolling, editing and selecting... set the `textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero` and `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0` to Zero.

Result:

[image]

Code (`@IBDesignable` so we can see it in IB / Storyboard):

```
@IBDesignable
class TextViewLabel: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks!! :)

Comment: @kelalaka - whoops... fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, Apple is following typography rules. The last line of a paragraph should not have a single word as the white space is jarring to the reader, supposedly.

If the last word and any trailing punctuation is more than 10 characters then the rule does not apply. This can be achieved by adding trailing spaces. On the provided example, only two spaces are needed as "Dummyuer?" is 9 characters:

[image]

To turn off this rule directly, remove the options for the label's line break strategy like this where testLabel is the UIKit IBOutlet:

```
testLabel.lineBreakStrategy = NSParagraphStyle.LineBreakStrategy()
```

Or like this:

```
testLabel.lineBreakStrategy = []
```

All of the above will result in the string wrapping as desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> This code can be used in fixed width label and it will overcome that,
>   also can get the height of the label

```
  private static func calculateLabelProperties() -> (String, CGFloat){

    let titleString = "Your string here"

        let wordArray = titleString.components(separatedBy: " ")
        var lineCount = 1//first line denoted by 1
        var tempWidth:CGFloat = 0
        var title = ""
        for (index,element) in wordArray.enumerated() {
            let width = calculateFontSize(title: element + " ", fontName: "your font name", fontSize: 17).width
            tempWidth = tempWidth + width

            //get the nextelement
            var nextElement = ""
            if wordArray.count > index + 1 {
                nextElement = wordArray[index + 1]
            }

            let nextElementWidth = calculateFontSize(title: nextElement, fontName: "your font name", fontSize: 17).width

            if tempWidth + nextElementWidth > 410 {//410 is labelwidth
                tempWidth = 0
                lineCount += 1
                title = "\(title)\(element)\n"
            } else {
                title = "\(title)\(element) "
            }
        }
        return (title, CGFloat(lineCount * 20))//20 is label sigle line height
    }
```

this code calculate font size

```
func calculateFontSize(title: String, fontName: String, fontSize: CGFloat) -> (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
    let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)
    return (title.size(OfFont: font!).width, title.size(OfFont: font!).height)
}
```

get font size

```
extension String {
    func size(OfFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        return (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
    }
}
```